# Delete and Update JPA entity using Spring Data CRUD repository

Tags: jpa, spring-data

If we have an entity `A` which contains a `List` of instances of entity `B` and entity `B` contains a `List` of instances of entity `C`, something like:

```
@Entity
class C { ... }

@Entity
class B {
  @OneToMany
  List<C> c;
}

@Entity
class A {
  @OneToMany
  List<B> b;
}
```

Is there a way to delete instances of `C` and update an instance of `C` from `SimpleJPARepository` based on entity `A`?

Comment: Do you also want to delete entity B? or just entity C and A ?

Comment: Can you add the operations that need to take place on instances of `A` and be cascaded to instances of `C` to the question? The answer depends on what operations are you performing on `A`.